# How to use milestones in Ticgit?

Tags: git

**Puzzle 1: where can I see the milestones?**

```
$ ti milestone Couchdb -n "instructions for backbone" -a "Read https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit and http://backbone.iriscouch.com/backbone-couchapp/_design/backbone_example/index.html
$ ti milestone
$ I cannot understand why here nothing?!
```

**Puzzle 2: which branch should I edit to edit tickets, milestones etc?**

```
$ git branch
* master
  ticgit
```

**Puzzle 3: why did the puzzle 1 -command not work? Look there is nothing?!**

```
$ ti list

   TicId  Title                    State Date  Assgn    Tags                
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Perhaps related**

1. [Version control for tickets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218069/version-control-for-tickets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the current active maintainer for TicGit-ng which presumably is what you're using (as opposed to TicGit, the now un-maintained version).

1) For some reason the old developer wrote the documentation and even the '--help' output for the `milestone` command, but never actually implemented the command. :(  This is a quite glaring bug, and as such [a ticket has been filed the Github Issues page](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit/issues/45) for TicGit-ng which I will address as quickly as possible.

2) You should never have to checkout the `ticgit` (or `ticgit-ng`) branch unless you need to do manual repairs for some reason.  To add a comment to the ticket you currently have checked out for example, if you are currently on the master branch you stay on that branch, and use the command `ti comment`. It will open [the editor defined in](http://kb.eukhost.com/changing-the-default-text-editor-in-linux/) `EDITOR` where you type the desired comment, and close the editor.  To then see the ticket with your new comment, use the command `ti show`, which will show you the currently checked out ticket.

3) 3 didn't work because of 1. Don't know why it was originally written like that, but I will implement that feature as soon as possible.

4) in 2 I mentioned the idea of a 'currently checked-out' ticket, in order to comment or otherwise operate on a ticket in TicGit-ng it is common practice to checkout said ticket.  This is not a requirement, because some commands can be used by specifying the ticket to operate on as an argument. To tell if you currently have a ticket checked out or to tell which one is currently checked out, use the command `ti list`, and look for the ticket with the `*` in the far left hand column -- the `*` denotes ticket you have checked out. To checkout a different ticket, you can either do `ti checkout 2` which will check out the ticket that is second from the top, or you can do (for example) `ti checkout e17222` which would checkout the ticket with the id of 'e17222'. Ticket IDs are determined by a hash of part of the ticket and are immutable. The ticket ID is the column second from the left in the output of `ti list`.

Because StackOverflow is not the place to file bugs, I have to ask that we continue discussion related to the bug itself over on the Github Issue that is linked to above.  If you need any more help with TicGit-ng please don't hesitate to contact me via Github or email.

Answer (score 0):

They are not yet implemented and documentation missing -- arg. Bug [here](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit/issues/45) reported:

> It seems like there are a lot of these little unfinished stubs where
>   the original author documented a behavior he/she hadn't actually
>   written yet, or conversely didn't documented the behavior fully. As I
>   mentioned on the other issue, I'm pressed for time right now with
>   other real world issues at the moment but I intend to rectify these as
>   quickly as possible.

5 months old, arg...ticgit not ready yet for mature use?