# How can I see Github -style things such as punchcards and timeline of git -repo?

Tags: git

I am looking for a software that would visualize the working with git -repo. I like some features of Github and some features of Bitbucket so I don't want to use them because they are not perfect. I am looking for ways to create similar visual features. Below you can find some parts but a lot of puzzles are still missing -- so how can I create Github -style things such as punchcards and timeline of git -repo?

**Some parts**

> 1. Gource [here](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) to vizualise commits
> 2. Gitolite [here](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/) to manage perms.
> 3. Ticgit [here](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit) to manage tickets but very incomplete (a lot of stuff not patched, for example, milestones apparently not patched more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251480/how-to-use-milestones-in-ticgit))

Answer (score 7):

[image]
**Installation on Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install python python-cairo 
git clone https://github.com/guanqun/git-punchcard-plot.git
cd git-punchcard-plot/
sudo cp git-punchcard /usr/local/bin
```

**Usage:**

1. Go to your repository directory.
2. Type in console: git punchcard!
3. Open: output.png

reference : 
git repo : https://coderwall.com/p/lxygq

Answer (score 1):

From what I know there currently is no tool to allow that. I researched on that topic myself and couldn't find anything really useful. Nonetheless a very similar question was already asked at:

[Generating statistics from Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository)

You should take a look at the suggestions posted there.

Answer (score 1):

Dustin Sallings has [nice timecard scripts and a few others](https://github.com/dustin/bindir) on github.

Answer (score 0):

[tig](https://github.com/jonas/tig) is an awesome command line client for git. It uses ncurses, and has many vim-style and emacs-style keybinds. While tig is a git client (not a GitHub client) you can still browse commits, see your commit history tree, make commits, edit your stage, view diffs, and much more. For visualization tools for more specific aspects of a git repo, see the other answers.

**Main and Diff View**
[image]

**Tree View**
[image]
<sub>(source: [nitro.dk](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/screenshots/tree-view.png))</sub>